# Time method for MongoDB collec

Tags: mongodb, time, collections

I'm looking for a method that allows me to find out the time that one entry entered into the collection. I've done some research but can only find a Timestamp() method that forces a specific time onto a piece of data inside the collection. Does there exist something like a db.collection.Time(); ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure about what you are asking, but if you wish to get the time when a document was added to a collection and are using the default _id type then you can get the documents creation time like this in the shell:

```
> var d = db.test.findOne();
> d._id.getTimestamp();
ISODate("2014-12-30T13:13:28Z")
```

This is difficult to use in a query so it is better to create a date field with an ISODate() if you need to query the date.